# Add selectbox with values of relation in Symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm a Symfony beginner and I'm eager to learn more about Symfony, that's why I started a learning project.

I have a many-to-one relation (Type has many Games, but Game has 1 Type), and I would like to show a select box with a list of  "types" to choose from.

I get this error:

```
Could not load type "AppBundle\Form\choiceType"
```

This is my code:

GameController.php

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\Game;
use AppBundle\Entity\Type;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * Game controller.
 *
 * @Route("game")
 */
class GameController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Lists all game entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="game_index")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $games = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Game')->findAll();

        return $this->render('game/index.html.twig', array(
            'games' => $games,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new game entity.
     *
     * @Route("/new", name="game_new")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {

        $type = new Type();
        $type->setName('test');

        $game = new Game();

        $game->setType($type);

        $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\GameType', $game);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($type);
            $em->persist($game);
            $em->flush($game);

            return $this->redirectToRoute('game_show', array('id' => $game->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('game/new.html.twig', array(
            'game' => $game,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Finds and displays a game entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="game_show")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function showAction(Game $game)
    {
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($game);

        return $this->render('game/show.html.twig', array(
            'game' => $game,
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to edit an existing game entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="game_edit")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function editAction(Request $request, Game $game)
    {
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($game);
        $editForm = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\GameType', $game);
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('game_edit', array('id' => $game->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('game/edit.html.twig', array(
            'game' => $game,
            'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Deletes a game entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="game_delete")
     * @Method("DELETE")
     */
    public function deleteAction(Request $request, Game $game)
    {
        $form = $this->createDeleteForm($game);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->remove($game);
            $em->flush($game);
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('game_index');
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to delete a game entity.
     *
     * @param Game $game The game entity
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createDeleteForm(Game $game)
    {
        return $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('game_delete', array('id' => $game->getId())))
            ->setMethod('DELETE')
            ->getForm()
        ;
    }
}
```

Update #3:

```
GameType.php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\TextType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class GameType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add( 'name', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Game',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'label' => 'name'
            ] );
        $builder
            ->add( 'name', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Type',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'multiple' => false,
                'expanded' => false
            ] );


    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Game'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_game';
    }


}
```

Entity\Game.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;


/**
 * Game
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="game")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\GameRepository")
 */
class Game
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Type", inversedBy="games")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $type;



    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $name;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Game
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $type
     */
    public function setType($type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;
    }



}
```

Entity\Type.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;


/**
 * Type
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="type")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\TypeRepository")
 */
class Type
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Game", mappedBy="type")
     */
    private $games;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->games = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;




    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Type
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getGames()
    {
        return $this->games;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $games
     */
    public function setGames($games)
    {
        $this->games = $games;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the symfony form component, then `choiceType` isn't correct. the class is `ChoiceType`, simply capitalize the C and add the `use` statement above class declaration.

EDIT: You also need to update your form component type if you are selecting an existing entity for that field.

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EntityType;

class GameType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name');


        $builder
        ->add( 'types', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Type',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'multiple' => false,
            'expanded' => true
        ] );


    }
```

extra reading on using entities and forms [Symfony Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html)

Comment: I've done that, now I get the following error: The option "class" does not exist. Defined options are: "action", "allow_extra_fields", "attr", "auto_initialize", "block_name", "by_reference", "choice_attr", "choice_label", "choice_loader", "choice_name", "choice_translation_domain", "choice_value", "choices", "choices_as_values", "compound", "constraints", "csrf_field_name", "csrf_message", "csrf_protection", "csrf_token_id", "csrf_token_manager", "data", "data_class", "disabled", "empty_data", (truncated) what does this mean?

Comment: ah, I see the mistake now. Updating my answer to help explain

Comment: Now I get this error: "Entities passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe persist them in the entity manager?
500 Internal Server Error ". I''ve changed the plural of types to singular because there is no plural variable of Type in my case. I will update my question with the current code. Thank you for your patience, bear with me please :)

Comment: are you passing an instance of your AppBundle:Type class to your form? If so, that maybe the reason for your error.

Comment: what do you mean with passing an instance of the Appbundle:Type to the form?

Comment: in your controller method that will display the form, what does that look like?

Comment: I've updated my question with code from my GameController, it's in "newAction"

Comment: remove `$type` and the call to set the type on the game in that `newAction` method

Comment: I'm so close, it shows the selectbox but it overwrites game.name input field, it's probably because they're both called name, how do I fix this?

Comment: the choice_label should be taking the value of whatever your Type's name property has. For your game name, you haven't specified an input component. `$builder->add('name');` should be something like `$builder->add('name', TextType::class, ['attributes_here']);`

Comment: Now it show this error: An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO type (name) VALUES (?)' with params [null]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null

Comment: curious, are you trying to create a type along with the game or just the game and selecting from an existing Type entity? If so, the persist statement for your Type needs to be removed

Comment: Yes it is and yes I did but no success, I had a textfield for the property "name", now that I have added a selectbox (also with  the property "name"), the textfield is removed from the form and replaced by the selectbox. I've updated my code in the GameType.php section

Comment: I've marked your answer as the solution because the problem was that I couldn't show the selectbox in my form, and now that works.

Comment: thanks, if you need help with whatever else issue you still had with your form, we can have a discussion elsewhere.

Comment: Great, how can I reach you? I don't have enough reputation to start a chat on SO. Btw, feel free to take a look at a issue I'm currently having: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42577817/formtype-duplicate-formfield-name-conflict/42580880#42580880

Answer (score 1):

In your case, You should use EntityType instead of ChoiseType.

```
       $builder
    ->add('type', EntityType::class, [
    'class' => Type::class,
    'choice_label' => 'name',
    'multiple' => false,
    'expanded' => true
```

Be aware of upper or lower.

Comment: I've done that but now I get this error: Unknown Entity namespace alias 'Type'.

Comment: You should Add the use statement.