# FormType duplicate formfield "name" conflict

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I have two properties with the same name from different tables declared in my GameType.php file.

But these are actually not the same values as the table columns Game.name and Type.name come from different tables.

How can I display both of them in the form without conflicts?

Snippet from GameType.php:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add( 'name', TextType::class, [
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Game',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
        ] );
    $builder
        ->add( 'name', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Type',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'multiple' => false,
            'expanded' => false
        ] );
}
```

They're both called 'name' which causes the Type's selectbox to override the Game's TextField.
I call the widget, but that's not working because they are both called 'name':

```
{{ form_widget(form.name) }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you change the properties name in the entity ? you can label them the same in the view after that if you need .

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: In your form builder, you can change the `name` to something that might better represent what you are selecting. in this case a `Type` . `builder->add( 'type', EntityType::class, [....])`

Comment: Thanks, I did that, now I get the error: "Entities passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe persist them in the entity manager?". I noticed others on Stackoverflow where having this error too, but I couldn't find the solution.

Comment: @AndrewNolan if you post this as your answer I'll accept it. 

I made a new question for the error "Entities passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe persist them in the entity manager?":
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42587779/symfony-error-when-inserting-new-game-entities-passed-to-the-choice-field-must

Comment: Did you change the first parameter of the $builder-add() method with the name of the field of your entity ?